# How to build the Rust compiler to use a custom fork of LLVM?

Tags: rust, llvm

AMD released an optimized version of the LLVM toolchain named AOCC. Rust uses LLVM as the native code generator. Is it possible to use this LLVM instead of the fork from the Rust team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [Rust 1ad094](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/1ad094d81c97b3d2dd8e980ccd1475a80647540d), when configuring Rust, you can pass various LLVM-related options:

```
./configure --help | grep -i llvm
    --enable-llvm-static-stdcpp    statically link to libstdc++ for LLVM
    --enable-llvm-link-shared      prefer shared linking to LLVM (llvm-config --link-shared)
    --enable-llvm-version-check    check if the LLVM version is supported, build anyway
    --enable-ninja                 build LLVM using the Ninja generator (for MSVC, requires building in the correct environment)
    --enable-emscripten            compile the emscripten backend as well as LLVM
    --enable-optimize-llvm         build optimized LLVM
    --enable-llvm-assertions       build LLVM with assertions
    --enable-llvm-release-debuginfo build LLVM with debugger metadata
    --llvm-root=VAL                set LLVM root
    --experimental-targets=VAL     experimental LLVM targets to build
    --build=VAL                    GNUs ./configure syntax LLVM build triple
    --host=VAL                     GNUs ./configure syntax LLVM host triples
    --target=VAL                   GNUs ./configure syntax LLVM target triples
```

If the version of LLVM in the fork you want to use is compatible with the version of LLVM that Rust needs, then you should just be able to use `--llvm-root=`

Comment: `--llvm-root` no longer seems to work for this purpose: `./x.py` will just clobber whatever was in that directory with a download of Rust's own LLVM fork.